# Mixed-integer (Linear) Programming (MILP) standard/canonical form

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

Is there a standard or canonical form for mixed-integer (linear) programming problems? For linear programms the standard form is sometimes given by:
$$
\max_{\boldsymbol x} \boldsymbol c^T \boldsymbol x\\
\text{s.t.} \boldsymbol{Ax} = \boldsymbol b\\
\boldsymbol x \geq \boldsymbol 0
$$
or$$
\max_{\boldsymbol x} \boldsymbol c^T \boldsymbol x\\
\text{s.t.} \boldsymbol{Ax} \leq \boldsymbol b\\
\boldsymbol x \geq \boldsymbol 0
$$
Mostly, the MILP problems are just explained by "require some variables to be integer" (e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming)). So I was wondering: Is there a standard form for MILPs or the more general MIPs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. For a pure integer linear program you can write it as an LP but specifying that your variables are integers. For a MILP you can write:

$$\begin{align}\max_{\boldsymbol x,\boldsymbol y} \boldsymbol c^T \boldsymbol x + \boldsymbol h^T \boldsymbol y\\
\text{           s.t. } \boldsymbol{Ax} + \boldsymbol{Gy} \le \boldsymbol b\\
\boldsymbol x \geq \boldsymbol 0 \\
\boldsymbol y \geq \boldsymbol 0& \text{ integral}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But is this also called "standard" form as for linear problems? I haven't found a reference for this, can you maybe provide one?

Comment: It comes from the textbook Integer Programming (Conforti et. al). Note that the canonical or standard LP is important for  theorems in duality theory and so on. I am not aware of theorems in integer programming where following a certain format to express the problem is important. So that is why you do not hear people talking about the canonical ILP or MILP formulation.